# Layer images on narrow DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to make vertical line in DIV.

then I want to layer img on vertical line.
(the pic shows the result I want)

For my source code is like this .

```
<div style="background-color:gray;width:1px;height:100%;"></div>
<img src="circle.png">

<img src="triangle.png">
```

How can I layer these elements???

[image]

Comment: your post does not show any efforts in achieving the task. Please update with the code to demonstrate the issue that you are facing. SO isn't a coding service after all.

Comment: "my source code is like this"  -> ???

Comment: I write down only the elements. In fact, I struggled many ways, but it a bit chaos.

Comment: For now my code is like this, but it is chaos...... `<div>
                <img style="border:solid;" src="/circle.png" style="position:absolute; left:10px;top:70px;" >
                <div style="background-color:gray;width:1px;position:absolute; top:90px;height:140px;padding:0px;"></div>
                </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do some math to adjust it in the center.

```css
.outer-flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.line {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70vh;
  left: calc(50% - 15px)
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-flex">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <img src="https://www.marylandeyeassociates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/red-dot-hi.png" width="21px" class="circle">

  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/60/60995.png" width="31px" class="arrow">
</div>
```

Comment: It works well for me.Thanks,  `display: flex;` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

The images are inside the div this way:

```css
div {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 1px;
  height: 200px;
}

img:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -10px;
  top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

img:last-of-type {
  margin-left: -10px;
  top: 85px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" />
</div>
```

If you know the width of the images, move them to the left with a negative margin of half their width.